# Is it possible to recover an email that has been clicked "delete forever" in the trash folder?

Tags: gmail, data-recovery

Is it possible to recover an email that has been clicked on "delete forever" in the trash folder?
I have accidentally clicked *delete forever* for an email but now I need to recover it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am sorry to say it is not possible to do so from within Gmail.

If the email was downloaded using Mozilla Thunderbird, Microsoft Outlook, or any similar software, and the mail client has not been synced since deletion, the messages can then be restored.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, there isn't an easy way to recover deleted email once you've done it forever.

The other answer on here is right - if you used another tool it might be possible.

Another option that might work (but is less likely), is to fill out a report of missing messages for the Gmail team to process: https://support.google.com/mail/bin/bin/request.py?&ctx=bugflow_receive31&contact_type=bugs

Gmail's help article says:

> If you've deleted a message permanently, by clicking Delete Forever in
>   your Spam or Trash, you won’t be able to recover the message using the
>   Gmail interface.

But you could use that bug request tool to describe directly to the team which email message(s) you need to recover and they might be able to help. Since this is meant for accounts that have been compromised, it might not work, but it's worth a shot.

Good luck :)

Comment: Important Note, while you can restore permanently deleted within the past 25 days for work/school accounts you can NOT recover messages deleted from the spam folder, that seems to be truly permanent.
[https://support.google.com/a/answer/6052340?hl=en]

Answer (score 3):

If this Gmail account was part of a work or school Google Apps domain, your admin can restore deleted email or Drive files for up to 25 days by following the step provided in this Google help article: [Restore a user's Google Drive or Gmail data](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6052340?hl=en)

This does NOT apply to consumer @gmail.com accounts.