# How to retrieve deleted emails several months ago?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

I have deleted my emails several months ago. But suddenly I require does email for legal purposes (serves as an evidence to a case). How can I retrieve those emails?

Comment: **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably out of luck, short of a court order.

Since Inbox uses the same data as Gmail, you might be able to recover recently-deleted messages using the methods in the answers to this question: [Is it possible to recover an email that has been clicked “delete forever” in the trash folder?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/34136/354)

But that only allows access to messages that have been deleted in, at most, the last few weeks. Google *may* have backups of the messages from before that, but they're not going to give them to you "just because". You'll most likely need to contact a lawyer and get a court order. Since you say this is for evidence in a legal matter, that should be possible.