# If I delete an email to the trash then delete those, is it deleted for good and frees up space on my computer?

Tags: gmail

If I delete an email and also delete it from trash, is it deleted for good and frees up space on my computer?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you move messages to the Trash and then empty the Trash, then yes, those messages are gone forever<sup>1</sup>.

But no, that will not free up any local storage, because your Gmail messages are stored in the cloud.

---

<sup>1</sup> You *may* be able to recover "permanently" deleted messages, but only if you do it soon after they're deleted. See: [Is it possible to recover an email that has been clicked "delete forever" in the trash folder?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/34136/354)